# Vue - Is it possible to style the html-element dynamically?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

**Short version:** In the `data()` of my app, I define certain colors. I want the `html`-element's background to one of these colors, based on a `switch` statement.

**Long version:**
In the `data()`, I've the following code:

```
data() {
    return {
      item: {},
      color1: '',
      color2: '',
    };
  },
```

In my `created()` function, I get the item from my backend. Furthermore I have written the following code to evaluate the colors for the `html`-section:

```
switch (this.item.itemType) {
    case 'car': this.color1 = '#39ac39'; this.color2 = '#00ff00'; break;
    case 'bus': this.color1 = '#3333ff'; this.color2 = '#1a75ff'; break;
    case 'plane': this.color1 = '#ff66cc'; this.color2 = '#ffb3e6'; break;

    default: this.color1 = '#'; this.color2 = '#';
}
```

In my `style` section, I want to style the background of my whole app (`html`-tag), to be styled like this:

```html
<style>
html {
  background-color: linear-gradient(to bottom, color1, color2);
}
</style>
```

Is this possible with Vue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible to bind a data inside your script to CSS rules in the style tag or any stylesheet file, the best way to deal with this is to define some CSS variables in the main CSS style file and change it using a script :

```
:root {
  --color1:#000;
 --color2:#fff;
}

html {
  background-color: linear-gradient(to bottom,var(--color1), var(--color2));
}
```

script :

```
switch (this.item.itemType) {
    case 'car': this.color1 = '#39ac39'; this.color2 = '#00ff00'; break;
    case 'bus': this.color1 = '#3333ff'; this.color2 = '#1a75ff'; break;
    case 'plane': this.color1 = '#ff66cc'; this.color2 = '#ffb3e6'; break;

    default: this.color1 = '#'; this.color2 = '#';
}

document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--color1", this.color1)

document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--color2", this.color2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Even though you cannot directly manipulate style tags or add `style` tags in the component's template you can use a trick to add dynamically generated stylesheets.

You can use [v-html](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML) to generate a dynamic style

```
<span v-html="style"></span>
```

taken from a computed property.

```
computed: {
    style() {
      return (
        "<style> html { background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, " +
        this.color1 +
        ", " +
        this.color2 +
        "); }</style>"
      );
    }
  }
```

But this will only exist as long as the component is in the tree view, once removed your style will also go.

[Here's](https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-euclid-tqb4k?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue) a working example.

Comment: Just for the record, I think @Boussadjra Brahim solution is better :)